# How to create an array of RBG colors?

Tags: java, arrays, colors

I have imported java.awt.Color; but cant find a method where I can write in the 3 color component values (red, green, blue) with a range from 0 -255. Is this not possible? If not, how can I easy create an array of colors?

```
import java.awt.Color;
```

Answer (score 0):

what about the constructors

```
Color(int r, int g, int b, int a)
Creates an sRGB color with the specified red, green, blue, and alpha values in the range (0 - 255).
```

or

```
Color(int r, int g, int b)
Creates an opaque sRGB color with the specified red, green, and blue values in the range (0 - 255).
```

?

```
new Color(255,255,255); //white
```

Answer (score 0):

You just have to create a new color:

```
Color a = new Color(arg0, arg1, arg2); //arg0 = red, arg1 = green, arg2 = blue
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use this Color constructor and the getRGB() method to get the color:

```
Color color = new Color(int r, int g, int b);
color.getRGB();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Color`'s constructor `Color(int r, int g, int b)` (see [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html#Color%28int,%20int,%20int%29))